# How to get the current HCURSOR of the current arrow cursor specifically in C?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm wondering how I can get the original HCURSOR of whatever happens to be set as the mouse arrow pointer. I've already tried using GetCursor(), but it just gets whatever cursor is currently displayed on screen. Here's a section of my code:

```
COLORREF *hide;
HBITMAP bmp;
hide = (COLORREF*) malloc(sizeof(hide) * 1);
bmp = CreateBitmap(1, 1, 1, 32, (void *) hide);
ICONINFO Ico;
Ico.fIcon = false;
Ico.hbmColor = bmp;
Ico.hbmMask = bmp;
HCURSOR c = CreateIconIndirect(&Ico);
HCURSOR orgc = GetCursor();
SetSystemCursor(c, 32512);
Sleep(10);
SetSystemCursor(orgc, 32512);
DeleteObject(bmp);
```

I intend for it to hide the cursor, then wait for ten milliseconds, then bring the original cursor back without having to use the resize trick. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'original'? The system default? The previous one used (before the last change)?

Comment: The one that was used, not system default.

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to get the current arrow pointer icon? I've seen software do it before when unfocusing the window.

Comment: @AdrianMole SetCursor returns the original? For me it just returns a boolean... unless you're not talking about SetSystemCursor().

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't know how you can do that (other than by adding code to remember what it was). I'm also saying that others *may* know how you can. (There are some really deep WinAPI experts here on Stack Overflow!)

Comment: @AdrianMole yes I know that, and that's what I plan to do, but I don't know how to get the arrow pointer icon specifically in the first place for it to be remembered. If you mean I'd have to make a driver or something to always be listening for it to be updated, then that sounds really inconvenient.

Comment: What happens if you call `LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)` after you have used `SetSystemCursor(myHCursor, OCR_NORMAL)`? Do you get the system default or your customized cursor? (Spoiler: I don't know!)

Comment: @AdrianMole I tried that, it just did nothing. Also for me it's 32512 instead of OCR_NORMAL, same thing though.

Comment: The `LoadCursor()` call itself won't *change* the displayed cursor. However, it *will* return an `HCURSOR` handle that you can then use in a call to `SetCursor()` ... I guess.

Comment: How is the system supposed to know which cursors are arrows? Any application could set any cursor that might or might not look like an arrow. On another operating system, the default cursor is an X which behaves like an arrow - would that count as an arrow?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Does this code not do what you wanted it to?

Comment: Have you tried ShowCursor(FALSE); Sleep(10); ShowCursor(TRUE); ?

Comment: @user253751 yes I did try ShowCursor(), it did absolutely nothing. Also, no it doesn't do what I need because it gets the currently displayed cursor instead of the arrow pointer specifically, so when I open it, it gets either the loading circle or the window size icon, and I want the arrow pointer.

Comment: To get the arrow pointer you use LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)

Comment: @user253751 doesn't that just get the default windows arrow cursor? EDIT: I just tried it, it does nothing.

Comment: @Humanagon Well which one do you want? Do you want the previous cursor, or do you want the arrow cursor? You have to make up your mind.

Comment: @user253751 I want the arrow cursor that the user has set, aka the default if they left it as default or custom if they set it to a custom one.

Comment: LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW) is what almost every program does to get the default arrow cursor, so they can display the default arrow cursor when the mouse is over their window.

Comment: @user253751 I understand that, but I don't want the default arrow cursor. I want the user-set arrow cursor so that I can put it back when the window is inactive or closed.

Comment: Does almost every program use the user-set arrow cursor? Then it seems reasonable to guess that LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW) returns the user-set arrow cursor. There is no GetSystemCursor, you use LoadCursor instead.

Comment: @user253751 I've been trying LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW) for the past 30 minutes now, and not only does it not give the user's arrow cursor, but it also just gives nothing.

Comment: is there an error code?

Comment: What's the specific reason you need to hide the cursor for a short time interval? Mind you, the time interval of 10ms is shorter than the refresh interval of a display running at 60Hz.

Answer (score 0):

> I intend for it to hide the cursor, then wait for ten milliseconds, then bring the original cursor back without having to use the resize trick. Any suggestions?

```cpp
ShowCursor(FALSE);
Sleep(10);
ShowCursor(TRUE);
```

I don't know what you mean by "the resize trick."

---

If you meant something else by "the original cursor," then perhaps a deeper understanding of how cursors are selected would be helpful.

Each window is responsible for setting the cursor as the mouse moves across it.  Whenever the mouse moves within a window then, assuming the mouse is not captured, that window will receive a WM_SETCURSOR message.  The name of the message can be a little confusing.  Think of it as a notification to the window that this is its chance to change the cursor.

The window procedure can choose its cursor shape by calling SetCursor and then return TRUE to indicate that no other handlers be given the opportunity to process the message.  There's nothing that denotes a particular cursor as an arrow cursor, wait cursor, crosshairs, etc.  It's just the currently selected shape.

This (normally) happens for each WM_MOUSEMOVE.  So it's very common for a window procedure to set the same cursor over and over again, so the system is designed to optimize for that.  But allowing the window to decide what to should after each mouse move gives the window the opportunity to show different characters depending on where exactly within the window the mouse pointer is.

Whenever a SetCursor calls specifies a different cursor than the current one, it returns the HCURSOR of the previously selected one.

Many window procedures do not explicitly handle WM_SETCURSOR messages and instead passes them on to the default window procedure (DefWndProc).  The default window procedure first relays the message to the parent window if there is one.  This can happen recursively so that the root ancestor is the first window to get a choice to change the cursor.

If the parent handles the message and returns TRUE, then processing stops.  So your application's main window can decide that the cursor should look like a chicken even if some of its child windows would want to select something else.

If no ancestor windows handle the message, then DefWndProc will check to see if the window has an HCURSOR set in its window class (WNDCLASS or WNDCLASSEX).  If the windows class does specify a cursor, then DefWndProc will set that as the cursor.  If the class cursor is NULL, DefWndProc does not set any cursor.

The system cursors are a set of defaults for different modes.  If an application wants a wait cursor, it can call `LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT)` and get the HCURSOR of whatever cursor the user has selected as the system's default wait cursor.  You shouldn't set the system cursors unless you're providing an interface for the user to set the system defaults.

Comment: By resize trick, I meant when you resize the windows cursor in your settings to put it back how it was. Also, I've already tried both ShowCursor(true) and ShowCursor(false), and they both did nothing.